# Exception 'Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, laravel

I have the error `Only variables should be passed by reference` on my `APIController.php`, I already read all the questions about this error but nothing fixed it.

My code :

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if (array_key_exists('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', $_SERVER)) {
    $ip = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
    $ip = array_pop(end($ip));
}
```

Error.log :

```
[2016-12-06 15:43:00] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Only variables should be passed by reference' in /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/Api/ApiController.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/Api/ApiController.php(33): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2048, 'Only variables ...', '/var/www/app/Ht...', 33, Array)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to save the end element of array into a variable then pass it into the method like this:

```
$arr = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
$ip = end($arr); // <------- This will give you the IP (no need of using array_pop)
```

> **'ErrorException' Explanation**: The problem is, that `end()` requires a reference, because it modifies the
>   internal representation of the array (i.e. it makes the current
>   element pointer point to the last element).

Hope this helps!

Comment: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given' in /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/Api/ApiController.php:34

Comment: Yeah the error is quite correct, you should pass array inside `array_pop()`

Comment: `$ip = end($ip)` Will give you the ip. No need for the `array_pop()`

Comment: @Pixel - I've updated the answer, please check it out - The `end()` will get you the IP

Comment: Thanks to my addition :P